# Can you mix white and multigrain flours?

Tags: bread, flour

I want to make a bread that's a mix of multigrain and white flour so that it's not overwhelmingly multigrain. Is mixing flours like this done? Does the ratio matter or is it just up to how I want it to taste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In fact, most bread recipes that use these flours have a base of white flour to which they are added.